# Alternatives for Html Helpers in ASP.NET Core Tag Helpers

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I would like to know the alternative way of the below Html Helper to Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core 2.0

```
@model string

<form asp-action="Encryption" asp-controller="System" method="post" asp-antiforgery="true">
    @Html.TextBox("InputText", Model, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessage("InputText")
</form>
```

I know that I could do this by using "asp-for" attribute while my view is bound to the Model. But here "InputText" is not a model property. It is just a string passed from controller action method.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="InputText">`?

Comment: Thanks and what about the @HTML.ValidationMessage(“InputText”).

Comment: There is hardly any point having `@HTML.ValidationMessage()` if its not a property associated with your model. It does nothing at all client side (there are no `data-val-*` attributes) and if you wanted to return the view with a `ModelStateError`, then you should have been using model anyway.

Comment: This is a code smell. Generally, when there's something you're trying to post, which is not part of your model, it's a sign that you're doing something you shouldn't be, like using your entity directly. Create a view model with the properties you need to post and then use that.